# Hashed pass, compare the result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passwords, bcrypt

I have a postgres datbase with a node backend.

```
  let hash = bcrypt.hashSync("mypass", 10);

  try {
    const queryString = `
        SELECT * 
        FROM users where username= 'admin' and password='${hash}'
  `;
```

This returns 0 rows.

Do I have to return the password and then run the compare?

```
 try {
        const queryString = `
            SELECT username, password
            FROM users where username= 'admin'
      `;

       bcrypt.compare(RETURNED PASSWORD, hash, function(err, res) {
          if(res) {
           // Passwords match
          } else {
           // Passwords don't match
          } 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes since the bcrypt algorithm creates different hash for same input, so you have to return hashed password and then compare it.